# Swapping Elements in Python Iteratively

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble understanding what's happening behind the scenes for this simple code snippet:

```
def changeArray(arr):
     for i in range(len(arr)):
         arr[i], arr[arr[i] - 1] = arr[arr[i] - 1], arr[i]
         print(arr)
     return(arr)
```

The code assumes the array has as its elements the integers from 1 to n.
The output for the given code when the input is [1,3,4,2] is:

```
[1, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 4, 3]
Out[8]: [1, 4, 4, 3]
```

while I was expecting it to print and return this:

```
[1, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Out[8]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Why are the values changing at all when the code is only swapping elements?

---

Edit:

It turns out, changing the swapping order fixes the problem:

```
def changeArray(arr):
     for i in range(len(arr)):
         arr[arr[i]-1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[arr[i]-1]
         print(arr)
     return(arr)
```

This gives the following output:

```
[1, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 4, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Out[8]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How did changing the order do the swapping as expected, and the reverse did something else entirely?

Comment: I think you probably want `arr[i - 1]` instead of `arr[arr[i] - 1]`

Comment: @damores arr[arr[i] - 1] would swap the element in ith index to a new index ind such that the new index will satisfy arr[ind] = ind + 1. Am I right in that reasoning?

Comment: `arr[arr[i] - 1]` takes an index equal to `arr[i] - 1` into `arr`. This means that the index of the element you swap is dependent on the value of the `arr[i] - 1`th element of `arr`. You don't want this to occur - the element positions you swap is independent of the value of the element.

Comment: Are you expecting this code to work for a list with larger elements, e.g. `[11, 12, 13, 14]`?

Comment: Oh no. I mentioned the assumption that all the elements in the array are from [1,n] where n is the length of the array

Comment: Be aware that a list of length _n_ only has indices up to _n_-1, so a better input list would be `[1, 3, 0, 2]`.

Comment: Yes. That is why there is arr[arr[i]-1] for all i's in the swap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you shouldn't use the object you're mutating to specify the target positions you want to replace, or it gets very confusing.

When you write this:

```
 arr[i], arr[arr[i] - 1] = arr[arr[i] - 1], arr[i]
```

It's roughly equivalent to:

```
tup = arr[arr[i] - 1], arr[i]
x, y = tup
arr.__setitem__(i, x)
arr.__setitem__(arr[i] - 1, y)
```

(Full details for how to translate this are [in the reference docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), but hopefully the inuitive idea is a lot simpler.)

Which should make it clear why you're getting the results you are. And also why all of the following do what you want:

```
x = arr[i] - 1
arr[i], arr[x] = arr[x], arr[i]

arr[arr[i] - 1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[arr[i] - 1]

def swap(x, y):
    arr[x], arr[y] = arr[y], arr[x]
swap(i, arr[i] - 1)
```

I think the first one is the simplest (the second one *looks* simple, but only misleadingly so).

Answer (score 0):

Changing your expression to

```
 arr[arr[i] - 1], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[arr[i] - 1]
```

is working for me. Still don't know how or why the values were changing. I am new to python as well sorry.

Comment: It gives me index out of range.